Populate embedded ._id in an Object without creating a separate collection for it
How do I populate an embedded and nested object from another collection?
User Schema:
const walletSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    balance: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },
    wallets: {
      type: [walletSchema],
      default: []
    }
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
export default User;

Expense schema:
const expenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
   },
   walletId: { // \<-- will store the respective wallet id of the User
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User.walets.walletId',     // \<-- THE PROBLEM
      required: true
   },
   amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
   }
);

const Expense = mongoose.model('Expense',expenseSchema);
export default Expense;

I embedded the wallets in the User object as I don't expect the user to have a thousand wallets and I will be accessing the wallets property frequently. Therefore, I didn't separate it into its own collection.
Is there a way to populate this field? Or do I have to do it manually? The user's expenses will be shown in a table displaying each expense's information
Expected result:
[{
  _id: new ObjectId('666418ed4e1b1ffa8ec19232'),  
  userId: {
    username: 'JohnDoe',
    wallets:[{
      _id: new ObjectId('666323b5fb1a3011bdc3ec29'),
      name: 'Savings',
      amount: 1234
    }]
  },  
  walletId: {
    _id: new ObjectId('666323b5fb1a3011bdc3ec29'),
    name: 'Savings',
    amount: 1234
  },  
  amount: 200,
}]


In userSchema you have defined wallets as an array of Subdocuments so they don't have their own collection. These are different from populated documents where you would store a ref to the document in it's own collection.  The ref needs a Wallet model and you don't have one. You have a number of options still available to you but it would appear you might benefit from just having wallets stored in their own wallets collection.

@jQueeny So i don't have any other option but to somehow manually get the corresponding wallet details through the populated userID?
What if i restructure the Expense model to embed the wallet details in the model? Though this might cause each instance to take up more space. A user could have thousands of expense logs.
What would be the optimal choice? The first method which takes less space but more logic. Or the second option of having less logic but taking up more space?

I wouldn't embed the wallet in the user and expense because you will then need to update the balance in two places. MongoDB has $lookup so you could do a Model.aggregate() query, lookup the userId and then get the wallet details from the populated userId.

Something like this aggregate query might do based on your existing schema designs.

You can use an aggregation without changing your schema like so:
const expense = await Expense.aggregate([
  {
    // Optional Stage: Match an expenses document
    $match: {
      "_id": req.params.id //< or from wherever you get an id
    }
  },
  {
    //Populate the expenses document with user details
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userId"
    }
  },
  {
    // Turn the new userId array field into just an object
    $unwind: "$userId"
  },
  {
    // Filter the wallets array to just get the one that matches walletId
    $set: {
      "walletId": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$userId.wallets",
          as: "wallet",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$wallet._id",
              "$walletId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Turn the new array into just an object
    $unwind: "$walletId"
  }
])

See HERE for a working example.

Great thanks it works! But how do i infer the type of the result without manually instantiating an interface/type?

Are you suing TypeScript? Your schemas don't suggest that. As per the docs "The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned).".
